# Bat script which creates ISO from a CD/DVD drive

Tags: batch-file, iso

Stack community good day! Thank you in advance for your time

I would like to create a bat file in order to autocreate an iso file from the DVD drive. So the logic will be:

1. Find which is the CD/DVD drive (from many drives)
2. And use that result as a variable (of the drive: for example F:) which will be executed in the following command:

   cdbxpcmd.exe --burn-data -folder:F:\ -iso:C:\donalds.iso -format:iso

So in the previous command, the F:\ will be the variable, lets say %input%:\ which the program cdbxpcmd will use in order to create an iso from that drive.

I have found the following script that finds the drive letter,
from here: https://itectec.com/superuser/windows-how-to-detect-dvd-drive-letter-via-batch-file-in-ms-windows-7/

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption^, drivetype') do (
  if [%%j]==[5] echo %%i
  )
endlocal
```

Do you believe that we could combine them? And how? Any suggestions?

Comment: a) yes. b) replace `echo %%i` with `set "input=%%i\"` and insert `cdbxpcmd.exe --burn-data -folder:%input% -iso:C:\donalds.iso -format:iso` before `endlocal` c) see b)

Comment: I guess I am not understanding what was stopping you from at least attempting to do it yourself? What's the worst that could happen? You maybe get an error and you learn from the error.

Comment: It would certainly be quicker if you specifically isolate the `DriveType` within the command parentheses, i.e. `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe LogicalDisk Where "DriveType='5'" Get DeviceID`.

Comment: @Stephan thank you very much your fast reply. I get some errors by running this. I will be back after testing this again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `cdbxpcmd.exe` itself to locate your drive:

Two line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) example:

```sh
@Set "CDBXP=C:\Program Files\CDBurnerXP\cdbxpcmd.exe"
@For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=()" %%G In ('^""%CDBXP%" --list-drives^"') Do @"%CDBXP%" --burn-data -folder:%%G -iso:"C:\donalds.iso" -format:iso
```

*Just change the location where you have your `cdbxpcmd.exe` command line utility between the `=` and the closing `"` on line `1`.*

---

Alternatively, you could still use WMI, but personally, I would not use Win32_LogicalDisk, I would instead use Win32_CDROMDrive, which could verify both that a CDROM disk is loaded, and that it contains readable data.

Single line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) example:

```sh
@For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Path Win32_CDROMDrive Where "MediaLoaded='True' And DriveIntegrity='True'" Get Drive /Format:MOF 2^>NUL') Do @"C:\Program Files\CDBurnerXP\cdbxpcmd.exe" --burn-data -folder:%%G\ -iso:"C:\donalds.iso" -format:iso
```

*Just change the location where you have your `cdbxpcmd.exe` command line utility, remembering to leave the doublequotes in place for best practice.*

Comment: Thank you very much @Compo. That did the trick, immediately! I ve tested your first example. Btw, I guess that it could not verify, as the second one, that the disk contains readable data ("MediaLoaded='True'). Right?

Comment: In the second example the boolean `DriveIntegrity` property is the one which reads a portion of the content and performs such a check, so feel free to use the same code without `And DriveIntegrity='True'`, however it is unlikely to be your issue. To check just try the command in a Command Prompt window, and look at its output: `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Path Win32_CDROMDrive Get Drive, DriveIntegrity, MediaLoaded /Format:List` Try it without a CD/DVD-ROM disk in the drive, with a readable CD/DVD-ROM disk, and with a blank CD/DVD-ROM disk.

Comment: Thank you again for your help! I will test it out.